# Laravel 4 where in condition with DB::select query

Tags: php, laravel

I have next SQL query:

```
SELECT summary_table.device_id, WEEKDAY(summary_table.day) as day, AVG(summary_table.shows) as avg_shows
    FROM (
         SELECT device_id, day, sum(shows) as shows
         FROM statistics
         GROUP BY device_id, day
    ) as summary_table
    WHERE device_id IN (1,2,3) // Just for example
    GROUP BY device_id, WEEKDAY(day)
```

How should I execute this using Laravel? I put this query in DB::select function, but how can I place all ids in "WHERE device_id IN (?)" condition? I tried using "array(implode(',', $var))" but it doesnt work. If I have ids like "13, 14" I get results only for id = 13.

So the question is how to place instead of "?" array of ids?

Comment: Show code that you tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel is using PDO library. Sadly, binding with PDO doesn't work with `WHERE IN`. You can read about it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

So what you have to do is to put prepared string in your query like this:

```
"(...)
    WHERE device_id IN (".array(implode(',', $var)).")
    (...)"
```

Comment: I thought about it. The only trouble is to prevent SQL injection. I've always trusted laravels functions like ->where(). Should I loop through $var and convert in to int like (int)$item before putting it inside implode?

Comment: Yes you're right with sql injection danger. You should convert all $var elements into integer.

Comment: The best option with converting is `intval` in my opinion: http://us1.php.net/intval

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the docs here, scroll down to "Using Where In With An Array":

http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries

The `whereIn` method takes an array, so pass in `$var` directly, no need to implode.

```
->whereIn('device_id', $var)
```

Comment: I can write DB::select('..')->whereIn together?

Comment: The docs on that page are for the query builder, not a manual sql query

Comment: Well I use manual sql query. It seems a little bit difficult to put that query inside query builder?

Comment: Because of your subquery? Sure it'll be a bit tricky. You can look at http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres to see how subqueries work with the querybuilder. Ultimately I think you either use query builder to take advantage of proper binding, or go with @Kasyx's answer and do it manually all the way.

Comment: ->whereIn('device_id', $var) this will work with. DB::table() not with DB::select().

Answer (score 0):

```
"(...)
    WHERE device_id IN (".implode(',', $var).")
    (...)"
```