# Eloquent WHERE IN using raw query / capsule manager

Tags: php, sql, eloquent

I want to write this query in eloquent using raw queries :

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE other_table_id IN (1,2,3)
```

I've tried writing it like this :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;
$insert_db = DB::select("SELECT products_id FROM products WHERE products_id IN (?)", [[265792,265787,265743]])
```

But this is giving me an empty array as a result.

What is the correct way of writing this using the capsule manager? (I absolutely need to do it using `DB::select`)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977291/laravel-4-where-in-condition-with-dbselect-query) is asking the same thing, back in 2013. Back then it was not possible. So did that change today? Can we use `WHERE IN (?)` in the latest versions of eloquent? Knowing that I NEED to use `?` for security, and not concatenate the string or it would be meaningless to use PDO at all.

**EDIT :**

The question is more about dynamic values. I can't use :

```
DB::select("SELECT products_id FROM products WHERE products_id IN (?, ?, ?)", [265792,265787,265743]);
```

Because the array `[265792,265787,265743]` is being built elsewhere. So imagine the following code

```
foreach($test as $k => $v) {
    $arr[] = $v['something']
}

DB::select("SELECT products_id FROM products WHERE products_id IN (?)", [[$arr]]);
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong, you want `INSERT INTO ... WHERE SELECT products_id FROM tbl WHERE IN()...`.

Comment: @Script47 yeah I changed the query to have a simpler example, as I failed to rewrite the simplified version of the insert query :-) Kindly take a look

Comment: '*But this is giving me an empty array as a result.*' - Do you have rows which actually exist for those values?

Comment: @Script47 of course, I wouldn't have posted the question otherwise. `SELECT products_id FROM products WHERE products_id IN (265792,265787,265743)` does give me a result. The question is how to get those results using eloquent's PDO

Comment: If you enable the query log (`DB::enableQueryLog()`) and then output the log (`DB::getQueryLog()`), what does it show?

Comment: @Script47 `DB::getQueryLog()` also returns an empty array.

Comment: You need a placeholder for every binding: `WHERE products_id IN (?, ?, ?)`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir that's a good idea if you know the amount of `?` you need, but what if you don't?

Comment: In what scenario would you not know the amount?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir question updated

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I'm using the latest version of *eloquent*. I'm not using Laravel. Per my tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner approach to generate the `?,` placeholders is to use [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php):

```
$in = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
```

### Edit #1

To handle instances where you have zero items in your array, I came up with the following function:

```
function in($arr)
{
  return count($arr) > 0 ? str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?' : false;
}
```

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/ThistleGleefulFraction)

Comment: This won't work in the case of if `count($arr)` is equal to zero. As it'll always give 1 `?` and when `count($arr) == 0` we'd want no exclamtion marks.

Comment: And if there are not results, in mysql, false won't return an error?

Comment: I guess, you'd first validate your array, if values exists, run the where in, otherwise don't and give an error message as correct values have not been passed (or something like that).

Comment: @GiveMeFreedomOrGiveMeFire use the pre-edit code and validate before the query to check if the array has values.

Answer (score 2):

You need a placeholder for every binding:

```
$placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($arr), '?'));
DB::select("SELECT products_id FROM products WHERE products_id IN ($placeholders)", [$arr]);
```

In Laravel/Eloquent 5.7.17+, you can use `insertUsing()`:

```
DB::table('table')->insertUsing(['foo', 'bar'], function ($query) use ($arr) {
    $query->from('other_table')
        ->whereIn('other_table_id', $arr);
});
```

Note that the method requires you to specify the column names (`['foo', 'bar']`).

Comment: This might not be the cleanest answer but it's a correct answer nonetheless, I wish eloquent had a built in method to do that... thanks!

Comment: I've added an alternative solution.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind if I ever move to the use of `DB::table` which I might in the very near future, thanks once more.